# É possível de alguma forma fazer sobrecarga de funções em C?

Tags: c, funções, sobrecarga

Já programo a um tempo em C, de forma procedural, porém há alguns messes comecei a programar orientado a objetos. Em Java, é possível fazer sobrecarga de funções. Como Java é uma linguagem orientada a objetos que foi desenvolvida com base na linguagem C, imagino que de alguma forma é possível fazer sobrecarga de funções, assim como posso fazer em Java, pois é de muita utilidade para mim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

- através de macros e códigos complexos ([exemplo](https://locklessinc.com/articles/overloading/))
- através de alguma ferramenta externa
- criando um padrão de nomes que facilite
- usar `_Generic()` disponível em C11
- criando um sistema dinâmico de variáveis

Tem limitações, fica feio, não recomendo, mas é possível.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Imaginei, por ser uma linguagem procedural. Vou iniciar meus estudos em C++ então. Eu já uso as docs de cplusplus mesmo. Mas, se é limitada, não vale a pena dizer que tem como. Ou pode, ou não pode.

Answer (score 2):

Em C, não. Em C++, sim. Você pode desenvolver em "C" e compilar como C++ só para usar os recursos C++ que lhe interessam, no caso sobrecarga de função.